# how to store the python variable's value inside the database in phpmyadmin?

Tags: python, mysql

I created a python list variable called 'coordinates'. The coordinates list consists of the x-axis and y-axis value pairs of random points in a graph.
The first value in a pair represents the x-axis value and the second value represents the y-axis value. The coordinates list variable seems like below.

```
coordinates = [(95, 171), (54, 131), (125, 131), (213, 78)]
```

I have implemented a function called 'direction_finder' to find cardinal directions by using those x-axis values and y-axis values in the coordinates list variable.

The implementation steps of the function as follows

1.access to x-axis values in each pair in the coordinates list variable.

```
 x1 = coordinates[0][0]
 x2 = coordinates[1][0]
 x3 = coordinates[2][0]
 x4 = coordinates[3][0]
```

2.access to y-axis values in each pair in the coordinates list variable.

```
 y1 = coordinates[0][1]
 y2 = coordinates[1][1]
 y3 = coordinates[2][1]
 y4 = coordinates[3][1]
```

3.Take the value of the degrees of x-axis and y-axis values.

```
degrees_x1y1 = math.atan2(x1,y1)/math.pi* 180
degrees_x2y2 = math.atan2(x2,y2)/math.pi* 180
degrees_x3y3 = math.atan2(x3,y3)/math.pi* 180
degrees_x4y4 = math.atan2(x4,y4)/math.pi* 180
```

4.Add an if condition to take the final degree value.

```
if degrees_x1y1 < 0:
    degrees_final_x1y1 = 360 + degrees_x1y1
else:
    degrees_final_x1y1 = degrees_x1y1


if degrees_x2y2 < 0:
    degrees_final_x2y2 = 360 + degrees_x2y2
else:
    degrees_final_x2y2 = degrees_x2y2


 if degrees_x3y3 < 0:
    degrees_final_x3y3 = 360 + degrees_x3y3
else:
    degrees_final_x3y3 = degrees_x3y3

 if degrees_x4y4 < 0:
    degrees_final_x4y4 = 360 + degrees_x4y4
else:
    degrees_final_x4y4 = degrees_x4y4
```

5.Create an array for Cardinal Directions.

```
direction_brackets = ["NORTH", "NORTH-EAST","EAST","SOUTH-EAST","SOUTH","SOUTH-WEST","WEST","NORTH-WEST"]
```

6.round the final degree values

```
round_x1y1 = round(degrees_final_x1y1/45)
round_x2y2 = round(degrees_final_x2y2/45)
round_x3y3 = round(degrees_final_x3y3/45)
round_x4y4 = round(degrees_final_x4y4/45)
```

7.Get the final cardinal directions for final degree values

```
final_direction_x1y1 = direction_brackets[round_x1y1]
final_direction_x2y2 = direction_brackets[round_x2y2]
final_direction_x3y3 = direction_brackets[round_x3y3]
final_direction_x4y4 = direction_brackets[round_x4y4]
```

8.return the final cardinal direction values

```
 return final_direction_x1y1,final_direction_x2y2, final_direction_x3y3, final_direction_x4y4
```

9.create a list variable called directions_list to gather the final cardinal directions values returned by the direction_finder function.

```
direction_list = []
direction_list= direction_lookup(coordinates)
```

10.Get the final cardinal directions from the 'direction_list' variable.

```
direction_x1y1 = direction_list[0]
direction_x2y2 = direction_list[1]
direction_x3y3 = direction_list[2]
direction_x4y4 = direction_list[3]
```

After implemented the code, I had to create the database connection to store the final cardinal directions in the PHPMyAdmin database.I created a database and a separate table to store the final cardinal directions. The code for those stpes are as follows.

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="directions")
cursor = connection.cursor()
directionsCollect= """Create Table directions_store(
    id Int(11) Primary Key Auto_Increment,
    cardinal_directions Varchar(255),
)"""


cursor.execute(directionsCollect)
```

After that I implemented the insert command to insert a direction to the created table.

```
record_x1y1 = """Insert Into directions_store(id, cardinal_directions)
Values(%(cardinal_directions)s)""",
{
   'cardinal_directions': direction_x1y1
}

cursor.execute(record_x1y1)

#commit the connection
connection.commit()

#close the connection
connection.close()
```

But the problem is that the insertion was not happend. The error said as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "floor_plan_detector.py", line 320, in <module>
 cursor.execute(record_x1y1)
  File "/home/sameera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 163,    in execute
  result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/sameera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
  conn.query(q)
 File "/home/sameera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 504, in query
  self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/home/sameera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 762, in _execute_command
  packet = prelude + sql[:packet_size-1]
  TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes
```

The error said the type error. Can anybody explain what's the wrong in here?.

Comment: You are not actually formating your string but passing a tuple to the function. record_x1y1 = "THE QUERY", params = {"the": "param"}, and cursor.execute(record_x1y1, params)

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is not a database, is a PHP software to manage a MySQL database. You shouldn't store your directions as varchar column. It is better if you use two numerical columns, one for each of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

How you are doing it aside,

In your lines:

```
record_x1y1 = """Insert Into directions_store(id, cardinal_directions)
Values(%(cardinal_directions)s)""",
{
   'cardinal_directions': direction_x1y1
}

cursor.execute(record_x1y1)
```

You are creating a tuple: record_x1y1 of type tuple(str, dict)
Then passing it to the function as such.

The pymysql's cursor.execute then tries to do something with it but it is not something it knows, thus the error.

What you should do is define the query and params seperately:

```
record_x1y1 = """Insert Into directions_store(id, cardinal_directions)
Values(%(cardinal_directions)s)"""

params = {
   'cardinal_directions': direction_x1y1
}

cursor.execute(record_x1y1, params)
```

Or you could unpack the tuple to args:

```
record_x1y1 = """Insert Into directions_store(id, cardinal_directions)
Values(%(cardinal_directions)s)""",
{
   'cardinal_directions': direction_x1y1
}

cursor.execute(*record_x1y1)
```